# Circular Dependency issue using Ruby on Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently use a rails starter kit for a project which can be found [here](https://github.com/starterkits/rails4-starterkit).This allows for a simple login, home page, monitoring, etc. This starter kit uses rails 4.1.8 and ruby 2.1.3.

I am currently now trying to get the a dashboard gem to work called [dashing rails](https://github.com/gottfrois/dashing-rails). It's compatible with rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0.

I allowed authorization to my localhost by adding the appropriate path for it. I am able to get the page to show, however when I load the page it comes out incomplete but sometimes it's different. Below is a picture with the buzzwords and convergence incomplete. They should have more information in them. This package using active support and requires redis server. It also requires multiple threads.

[image]

Yes I did try the curl command.

The problem I believe has to do with some dependency issue, as stated by the log, but I am new to rails so any help with trying to resolve this issue or the cause would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the error file

```
  RuntimeError (Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Dashing::WidgetsController):
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:478:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:240:in `const_get'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:240:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:552:in `get'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `constantize'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:78:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `controller'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:46:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack-pjax (0.8.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  airbrake (3.2.1) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  airbrake (3.2.1) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (3.2.1) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.8.273) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/server.rb:492:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/server.rb:363:in `process_client'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `call'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It really helps us if you take the time to use better writing style in your question. Instead of lumping everything into a single paragraph, break it apart for readability. That encourages people to respond as they're more easily able to understand what you're asking.

Comment: This post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790755/circular-dependency-detected-while-autoloading-constant-rails-4-ruby-2) seems to imply that the issue is related to trying to accidentally use a new ruby reserved keyword. This post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013055/circular-dependency-detected-while-autoloading-constant-user) seems to imply that it could be a problem with with the location of your controller files. From what I have been able to find, the latter post is the most common scenario. Take a look at your controller/rout setup and see if those match up? I k